# Use grep on a specific column from text Bash Linux

Tags: linux, bash

Got a quick question.

Basically I´m looking to get the lines/rows from a text file in which column starts with a specific number.
The example lines from the text file I´m getting the info are

```
1      :    ACTIVO              :       :   0
11     :    ACTIVO CIRCULANTE   :   1   :   0
111    :    CAJA                :   11  :   0
11101   :   CAJA GENERAL        :   111 :   0
11102   :   CAJA CHICA          :   111 :   0
```

every row separated by ":"  Im looking to get for example.. the first row by using the number "1". It will show me the line 1, the one Im looking for. but also will show me the line that starts with "11" since has "1" in the third column.

I´m using this so far and is the code that I need to fix

```
grep -w "$cuenta" $documento | cut -d":" -f1,2,4
```

where $cuenta holds the number I want, for example: 1 and $documento is the txt file I´m using.
Which will print me the column 1, 2 and 3 from the text but also will print 2 lines, the one with 1 and 11 since as I stated before, has 1 in the third column

Is there a way to use grep to use the column 1 only?.
I´ll be using the code to catch certain column in a variable for later use.

Comment: `grep '^1[ ]' filename`  Use the regular expression to anchor the search to the first column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `awk` for these column based searches-

```
cuenta=1
awk -F: -v var="$cuenta" '$1 == var {print $0}' $documento | cut -d":" -f1,2,4
```

This will only match lines which have `1` in the first column.